# YapDatabase encryption with Carthage

Tags: cocoapods, carthage, yapdatabase

I'm trying to move my project from `cocoapods` to `carthage`. I'm using `YapDatabase` with encryption used by pod `pod 'YapDatabase/SQLCipher'`
Now when I removed pod and I've created `yapdb` framework with `carthage` I cant set `cipherKeyBlock`, compiler can't find it.

Comment: do your other Carthage frameworks work? did you follow [Carthage's steps here](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#adding-frameworks-to-an-application)?

Comment: yes, my other framework works, same as stand alone YapDatabase, but encryption is I guess different build?